# Additional Information to be added to Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

As I understand it, the idea for Careers 2.0 is for it to be **the** place for your CV. No longer shall we have CV's here, there and everywhere - Careers 2.0 is where it's at!

If Careers 2.0 is really going to be definitive place to store your CV then I think the following fields need to be available:

- Full Name
- Full Address including post/zip code
- Date of Birth
- Marital status
- Nationality
- Telephone Numbers
- Referee Details

All of these fields should, by default, only be visible to the logged in user so that they only appear on a printed copy of your CV.

If possible it would be quite nice to have these available on an online version of your CV. Maybe we set a secret key that we can provide with our public profile URL.  If a secret key is entered they get to see your full personal details otherwise they see the current version as it is.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why would you ever put your marital status on a CV?

Comment: @mmyers - some people do. I have no idea why but they do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to defer this. I like the idea of allowing more info on profiles (and different cultures have different customs when it comes to that). I also like the idea of being able to expose that selectively, although you'd have to be careful w/r/t implementation. We would need to add controls to the profile to allow you to determine what you want to show and what not. So, while I like the idea, I'm not convinced that the additional overhead is worth it.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. If you feel the overhead is too great at present that deferring is a good option. Maybe it will get implemented in future. Thanks